# IBM Domino - Error trying to connect to LDAP via SSL

Tags: java, ssl, lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

I can connect with the agent I created when I connect to port 389, but when I changed to port 686 for SSL I am getting the following error:

> HTTP JVM: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: localhost:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.g: No trusted certificate found].

I am thinking I must need to add the ssl certificate somewhere.

```
String nm = ldapdoc.getItemValueString("user");
String pass = ldapdoc.getItemValueString("Pass");

Hashtable ldapEnv = new Hashtable();
ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://localhost:636");
ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,nm);
ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);
ldapEnv.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"simple");

ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Kevin

Comment: Does this help? http://blog.darrenduke.net/Darren/DDBZ.nsf/dx/solution-domino-directory-assistance-to-active-directory-when-using-ssl-does-not-break-with-9.0.1-fp4.htm